# How to Replace() set by variables - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I need to change out the class "sash" in the div below with a new class depending on which radio button the user pushes on a form. The div is stored in a string.

```
jData = '<div class=\"hotspot F1hs sash\" id=\"F1\” >’

var radios = $(".rectangleRadios.active").children("input").val(); 

var windowName = $.urlParam('windowid’); // This is the F1. It comes from a URL parameter and will change from page to page.

var updateFrame = new RegExp(windowName+'hs','g’);  //Creates the F1hs

var id = new RegExp('\\" id=\\"'+windowName,'g’); // Creates the “  id=F1
```

So I'm trying to remove what ever class is in between F1hs and id then replace it with the selected 'radios' button.

```
jData = jData.replace(/updateFrame.+?id/, updateFrame+" "+radios+ id);
```

How do remove what is in between the two variables and add the new class?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var jData = '<div class=\"hotspot F0hs sash\" id=\"F1\” ><div class=\"hotspot F1hs sash\" id=\"F1\” ><div class=\"hotspot F3hs sash\" id=\"F1\” >';

jData = jData.replace(/(<div.*?class=".*?F1hs\s+.*?).*?(".*)/gi, "$1NEWCLASS$2");


    console.log(jData);
```

Outputs:

```
<div class="hotspot F0hs sash" id="F1” ><div class="hotspot F1hs NEWCLASS" id="F1” ><div class="hotspot F3hs sash" id="F1” >
```

Comment: Thank you! Close, but how do you mix a variable in there? F1hs will change depending on what is in the URL so that needs to be in the first part. Ex:<div\s+.*?class=hotspot"+updateFrame.

Comment: this  "$1hotspot F1hs NEWCLASS$2" is just a string.. so hotspot and everything is just static string.. change it to variables.. "$1"+ var1+ " " + var2 + "$2"

Comment: But I need the searching to be on the updateFrame variable, not the div for there will be multiple divs in the real working string. So I need help getting the variable mixed into the first part as I show in the ex. above.

Comment: updated my answer.. now mabe rewrite this to use new RegExp and add the variable where i have typed F1hs. I created a minor js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/73Lw74as/